# How do I fix Syntax Error at Input in Pinescript?

Tags: arrays, pine-script

Hey Im currently trying to build an indicator using chatgpt. Here is the code it gives me:

```
study("Volatility Factor", version=5)

// Number of bars to look back
bars_to_look_back = 20

// Initialize an array to hold the ranges of the last 20 bars
ranges = array.new(bars_to_look_back)

// Loop through the last 20 bars and calculate the range of each bar
for i = 0 to bars_to_look_back - 1
    HighLowrange = high[i] - low[i]
    ranges[i] = HighLowrange

// Sort the array of ranges in descending order
ranges_sorted = sort(ranges, "desc")

// Calculate the average of the top 10 ranges
top_10_average = (ranges_sorted[0] + ranges_sorted[1] + ranges_sorted[2] + ranges_sorted[3] + ranges_sorted[4] + ranges_sorted[5] + ranges_sorted[6] + ranges_sorted[7] + ranges_sorted[8] + ranges_sorted[9]) / 10

// Plot the Volatility Factor on the chart
plot(top_10_average)
```

I keep getting errors trying to run it. Specifically with "ranges[i] = HighLowrange" Syntax error.

I tried adding a double equals sign and messing around with the different spacing, but I couldnt seem to get rid of the error. Im also guessing there will be more errors after this one is fixed. Im new to coding so Im just wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to get this code to work? Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

To excess an element in an array, you use `array.get(id, index)`. For example, to get the first element of `ranges` array, you use `array.get(ranges, 0)` and not `ranges[0]`.

Similarly, in order to set an element at a specific index in an array, you need to use `array.set(id, index, value)`. For example, to set the value of `HighLowrange` as the first element of `ranges` array, you use `array.set(ranges, 0, HighLowrange)` and not `ranges[0] = HighLowrange`.

In addition, please note that in order to sort an array, you'll need to use `array.sort` and not just `sort`, and the order parameter is not a `string` but an `input sort_order` which takes only one of two option: `order.ascending` (default) or `order.descending`.